# 'Float' is not identical to 'UInt8' Swift

Tags: swift, taylor-series

I have no idea what's wrong with my code for a Taylor series:

```
func factorial(n: Int) -> Int {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)
}

func sin(num: Float) -> Float {
    let rad : Float = num * 1.0 / 180.0 * 3.1415926535897;
    var sum : Float = rad;
    for i in 1...100 {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum += Float(pow(rad, 2 * i + 1) / Float(factorial(2 * i + 1)));
        } else {
            sum -= Float(pow(rad, 2 * i + 1)) / Float(factorial(2 * i + 1));
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

print(sin(123.0));
```

Here are the errors:

```
<stdin>:11:17: error: cannot invoke '/' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue Float, $T25)'
sum += Float(pow(rad, 2 * i + 1) / Float(factorial(2 * i + 1)));
~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<stdin>:13:13: error: 'Float' is not identical to 'UInt8'
sum -= Float(pow(rad, 2 * i + 1)) / Float(factorial(2 * i + 1));
^
```

Comment: Why are you using different parenthesis for `sum +=` and `sum -=`?

Comment: I was trying two different ways of doing it. Both did not work.

Comment: Regardless of the errors you're seeing, your data types are insufficient to the task, mainly due to the ranges. And, even though `float80` has the range, the precision will bite you.

Answer (score 1):

The `pow` function needs two arguments of the same type, either `Float` or `Double`, and so does the division.

Change your `sum +/-=...` statements to:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
  sum += pow(rad, Float(2 * i + 1)) / Float(factorial(2 * i + 1))
} else {
  sum -= pow(rad, Float(2 * i + 1)) / Float(factorial(2 * i + 1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to deal with both Ints and Floats? Swift is **really** picky about types, so if you can stick to one, that will make your life way easier. With just Floats, you can get this working by adding a single line:

```
func factorial(n: Float) -> Float {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)
}

func sin(num: Float) -> Float {
    let rad : Float = num * 1.0 / 180.0 * 3.1415926535897;
    var sum : Float = rad;
    for i in 1...100 {
        let float_index :Float = Float(i) 
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sum += Float(pow(rad, 2 * float_index + 1) / Float(factorial(2 * float_index + 1)));
        } else {
            sum -= Float(pow(rad, 2 * float_index + 1)) / Float(factorial(2 * float_index + 1));
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `pow` requires its arguments to be of the same type but what you have isn't going to work even if you *do* sort out that issue. That's because your `factorial` function is generating numbers that are too big.

The largest 64-bit integral number has about twenty digits while the factorial of 200 has about 375.

Ergo it won't fit into a `Int`, it won't even fit into a `Double` (double precision IEEE754 number), which maxes out at about 308 digits (upper range, obviously precision is less).

You'll need to move up to `Float80` which provides for several thousand digits of range.

But, again, due to the limited *precision,* you're likely to introduce a lot of errors into your calculations. This would be true even with the IEEE754 *quad* precision, limited to about 34 decimal digits of precision.